# Amplify Update <category> overwriting template changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

We have a simple API Gateway api with 3 endpoints created via the amplify cli (`amplify add api`).

1. We made a couple of minor adjustments to the cloudformation template that amplify originally generated for this api in order to fit our needs (adding some additional headers and such)
2. Once we had everything set we pushed our changes via `amplify push`
3. We ran `amplify update api` to add a new 4th endpoint

However, we discovered that while amplify did add the fourth endpoint, it also reverted all of our changes to the original 3 endpoints. We need to be able to update this api without redoing all our changes each time. Is there a way to accomplish this?

**Note:**

We ran `amplify pull` to get all of our changes back from before we added the 4th endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this isn't supported.

Think of the CloudFormation script as a generated artifact from the CLI.

You will either want to *always* use the CLI, or decide to *never* use the CLI  and make manual updates from this point out.